# Save and load decimal in windows phone built-in database

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, decimal

I use a built-in database engine on my WP8 App.

When I save a decimal value, e.g. 3.5 the value is stored in the database as follows: 3.5000. When I load the value from the database 3.5000 will be shown in the TextBox. How can I change this behaivoir?

Note:
If I debug my code I see always 3.5M. Only the TextBox displays 3.5000.
By Default Windows Phone stores a decimal value as Decimal(29,4)

Thanks for help.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can format the value using [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when binding it to your TextBox in XAML e.g.

```
Text="{Binding Latitude, StringFormat=\{0:n2\}}"
```

I've not tried it myself, but the [general ("G") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) is probably what you're after. Have an experiment with the StringFormat property to achieve what you're after.